# MySQL Optimize Left Outer Join In Select

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to optimize the below query and python script. 
There are 100,000+ rows in `file` and about 300,000 items in `file`. It takes a very long time to run. Any ideas?

```
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=*,user=*,passwd=*,db=*, cursorclass=cursors.SSCursor)
cursor = db.cursor() 
print 'running large query'
cursor.execute('
SELECT `file`.`file_id`,`file`.`format` FROM `file` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `file_id`, `filename` FROM `file_version` WHERE `filename` = %s) AS `version` 
ON `file`.`file_id` = `version`.`file_id` WHERE `version`.`filename` IS NULL',[thumbnail]) 
results = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
for row in results
```

table file

> file_id (pk) | format | etc.

table file_version

> version_id (pk) | file_id | filename | etc.

Each file can have multiple versions, e.g. original.jpg, 300.jpg, 600.jpg, 800.jpg. The select inside a select is what is really slowing it down IMO. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if the SQL is slow by itself?

Comment: Yes, the SQL is what is slow. I also was looking into doing "for row in cursor.fetchone" which should decrease the memory usage but that wasn't working at the time.

Comment: If your table `file_version` does not have index on `filename` then every query like above will do a full table scan - from this you'll get bad performance.